# RxJava Event Bus

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Using first version of `RxJava` and `RxAndroid` I had following `class` as `EventBus`:

```
public class RxBus {
private static RxBus instance;
private PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

public static RxBus instanceOf() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RxBus();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setMessage(Object object) {
    subject.onNext(object);
}

public Observable<Object> getEvents() {
    return subject;
}
}
```

Getting instance via  `instanceOf` in any class I used `setMessage` method to emit messages and following code to get emitted messages:

```
  bus.getEvents().subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof String) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    });
```

`Action1` was from `rx.functions` package. Trying to migrate use `RxJava 2` I cannot import it.

Tell me please, what is the shortest way to use `RxJava 2` as `EventBus`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RxJava2, the `Action1` has been renamed to `Consumer`.

> The remaining action interfaces were named according to the Java 8 functional types. The no argument `Action0` is replaced by the `io.reactivex.functions.Action` for the operators and `java.lang.Runnable` for the `Scheduler` methods. `Action1` has been renamed to `Consumer` and `Action2` is called `BiConsumer`. `ActionN` is replaced by the `Consumer<Object[]>` type declaration.

See [What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#actions)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good implementation of event bus in RxJava2 (Code is copied from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/abdallahalaraby/6e68205c9f50f89e4a2ac1c17aa9ac48))

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class RxBus {
    private static volatile RxBus sRxBus = null;
    private PublishSubject<Object> mPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    private RxBus() {
    }

    public static RxBus getInstance() {
        if (sRxBus == null) {
            synchronized (RxBus.class) {
                if (sRxBus == null) {
                    sRxBus = new RxBus();
                }
            }
        }
        return sRxBus;
    }

    public <T> Observable<T> subscribe(Class<T> cls) {
        return mPublishSubject
                .filter(o -> o.getClass().equals(cls))
                .map(o -> (T) o);
    }

    public void post(Object obj) {
        mPublishSubject.onNext(obj);
    }
}
```